# c# short if statement not working with int? (int=null)

Tags: c#, if-statement, expression

I am trying to shorten my code by using short-if:

```
int? myInt=myTextBox.Text == "" ? null : 
    Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);
```

But I'm getting the following error:
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'int'

The following works:

```
int? myInt;
if (myTextBox.Text == "") //if no text in the box
   myInt=null;
else
   myInt=Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);
```

And if I replace the 'null' in integer (say '4') it also works:

```
int? myInt=myTextBox.Text == "" ? 4: 
    Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: This is not a short if, but a ternary operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
int? myInt=myTextBox.Text == "" ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: You guys all don't give much about int.TryParse hm :) ?

Answer (score 4):

What we need is to let the compiler know, that both parts of the if expression (if and else) are the same. And that's why C# contains the word **default**:

```
int? myInt=myTextBox.Text == "" 
   ? default(int?)
   : Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

My I suggest the following ?

```
int value;
int? myInt = ( int.TryParse(myTextBox.Text, out value ) ) ? value : default(int?);
```

Comment: It also handles the case that the string cannot be converted to a int, like malformed strings or overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
int? myInt=myTextBox.Text == "" ? (int?)null : 
    Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: While this _may_ technically answer the question your answer would be significantly improved if you also state _why_ it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number =!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp) ? Convert.ToInt32(temp) : (int?) null;
```